# Trouble communicating with router DHCP?

Tags: ethernet, router

my home network is has problems regarding linux computers, two ubuntu and two mint. I have had a look at the log files and searched the internet regarding the solution. I cannot find a whisker of a solution. One of the mint computers connects fine, the other three appear have this same problem. A PS3, Mac and all Windows connect fine.

I've tried:

- Disabling IPv6 (I don't think my router is IPv6 friendly)
- Using USB wlan device, internal WLAN device, and and Ethernet cable (all this work on other networks/windows)

So I suspect this is a problem with my computer(s) not being able to communicate with my router in a common language. But I'm not much of an expert. I hope someone will care to look at my log file I believe the answer is in here.

```
Jun 25 22:57:01 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested') [70 30 39]
Jun 25 22:57:01 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'user-requested') [39]
Jun 25 22:57:01 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3459
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> dhclient started with pid 3465
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: 
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/f6:d1:f2:c4:b1:6f
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/f6:d1:f2:c4:b1:6f
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:04 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:07 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jun 25 22:57:08 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:08 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:11 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jun 25 22:57:11 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:11 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:19 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jun 25 22:57:19 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:19 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:24 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Jun 25 22:57:24 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jun 25 22:57:24 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jun 25 22:57:24 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jun 25 22:57:28 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jun 25 22:57:28 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:28 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:29 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jun 25 22:57:29 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:29 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:31 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jun 25 22:57:31 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:31 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:36 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jun 25 22:57:36 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:36 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:39 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jun 25 22:57:39 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:39 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:47 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jun 25 22:57:47 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:47 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 dhclient: Discarding packet with bogus hlen.
Jun 25 22:57:49 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <warn> (eth0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Jun 25 22:57:49 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3465
Jun 25 22:57:49 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jun 25 22:57:49 joshua-Ideapad-Z570 NetworkManager[852]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
```

If I can add anything else which may help the diagnosis please add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can answer the question 50% now, since purchasing a new router the problem has dissipated. But I cannot explain why x of the computers were incompatible.